# EditText and Textview not displayed in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-relativelayout

Hey StackOverflow community.

I am working on an android app right now and I got some problem with the layout of a fragment.

My problem is that the textviews and edittexts are not displayed, they are like squeeze in the layout design mode of android studio. It's the same thing when I run the app in the emulator. I am using a relativeLayout and the gravity is set to bottom.

I have tried different thing like changing the gravity, the layout height for the relativeLayout and the textView/editText but nothing work. 
Here is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.project.vincent.activityplanner.InfoPanelActivity"
android:gravity="bottom">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/dateStart"
    android:text="test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/dateStart"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateStart"
    android:text="Start" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dateStart"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timeStart"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeStart" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timeStart"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeEnd"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/dateEnd"
    android:text="Start" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dateEnd"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timeEnd"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/timeEnd"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timeEnd"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Only the save button and the rating bar are displayed correctly.

**Layout Result**

[image: Layout result]

**Layout Expectation**

[image: Layout expectation]

If you have an idea on how to solve this problem I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: what result you want, attach screenshot

Comment: share your mockup here

Comment: I have just edited my post to add the result expected. Thanks

Comment: @Gnarkk I just copy and past your XML code, I seen  you are using relative layout and give circular dependency on layout.

for the example if you want rating bar at  at bottom please  use alignParentBottom= "true"

and write dependent  element below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.project.vincent.activityplanner.InfoPanelActivity"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="test2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dateStart"
        android:text="test3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dateStart"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateStart"
        android:text="Start" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateStart"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timeStart"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeStart" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/timeStart"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/timeEnd"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="End" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dateEnd"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ratingBar"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateEnd"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timeEnd"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/timeEnd"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/timeEnd"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout allows you to place elements "one after another".
use "layoutAlignComponent" section of your elements in desisgner to stick them to each other.
I can see you already tried with your `android:id="@+id/textView2"` as it has `android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"` field.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to remove the `android:gravity="bottom"` property from the parent relative layout then you have to add the following code to show your save button and rating bar in bottom

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

and then you have to remove the white color property from the textviews and  then after that you can see your textviews and align them as per your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent layout in linear layout.Because RelativeLayout is a view
group that displays child views in relative positions. The position of each view   can be specified as relative to sibling elements (such as to the left-of or below another view) or in positions relative to the parent RelativeLayout area (such as aligned to the bottom, left or center).

Your screen look like[image: [screenshot]]that after changing parent to linear.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.project.vincent.activityplanner.InfoPanelActivity"
android:gravity="bottom">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/dateStart"
    android:text="test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/dateStart"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateStart"
    android:text="Start" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dateStart"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timeStart"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeStart" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timeStart"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeEnd"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/dateEnd"
    android:text="Start" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dateEnd"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timeEnd"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/timeEnd"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timeEnd"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Do you mean change from relative to linear?

Comment: If you are using a relative layout then you should provide dependencies to their child views.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it get closer to what I am trying to do. yet I would like to place some element side by side, raatingbar and the save button for example. Should I use a relative layout (or any other layout) within the linearLayout to create those line with multiple element?